# How many test cases can we record through Robotium Recorder Free Version

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium, robotium-recorder

I am new to robotium and want to use it for my app testing. I have also downloaded robotium recorder for recording test cases and used it three times for recording. Now when I use it to record more test cases it ask for "license key" which I don't have as I am using a free version. Is there any work-around/configuration settings for using free version to record more test cases? please let me know if this is possible or not.

Your revert will be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The limit is currently 5 saved tests on the free trial ([source](http://robotium.com/pages/free-trial))

Even if getting around this restriction is possible (well everything is possible but it could be a lot of work) you would be breaking the terms and conditions of the license that you agreed to and open yourself up to a whole host of legal issues. Once you have reached the end of your free trial of recorded tests you are supposed to then have evaluated the product enough to know if you would like to purchase the license for a full years use or not. If you want to keep using it like it looks you do you will need to purchase a license [here](http://robotium.myshopify.com/products/robotium-recorder)